# Twilio Programmable Chat REST API response events

Tags: node.js, twilio

```
 twilioClient.chat.services(service_SID)
.channels
.each(channels => console.log(channels.sid));
```

From the above code, how can I check if the request is Success or not.

What I tried is :

```
 twilioClient.chat.services(service_SID)
    .channels
    .each(channels => console.log(channels.sid))
    .then(function (err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            //console.log('error ' + err);
            return res.status(500).send('Problem in retrieving channels');
        }
        res.status(200).json({
            message: 'Channels retrieved sucessfully',
            docs: docs
        });
    })
```

I need something like this to know the response. Did I need to promise?. I dont know about promise yet. Can someone pls provide an example or tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When using the `each` function to map over the remote resource, it's not using a Promise. `each` expects to work. However, you can provide a function to `each` that can be called once the request is complete or if there is an error. You can pass that function as the option `done` in the second argument. Here is how you would do that:

```
twilioClient.chat.services(service_SID)
  .channels
  .each((channel => console.log(channel.sid)), { done: error => {
    if (error) { 
      console.error("There was an error loading the channels.", error);
    } else {
      console.log("All the channels were successfully loaded.")
    }
  });
```

If you are looking to load the channels in one go, then `each` might not be the right function for you. You can also use `list` which returns the list of channels rather than a channel at a time. For example:

```
twilioClient.chat.services(service_SID)
  .channels
  .list({ limit: 50 }, (error, channels) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error("There was an error loading the channels.", error);
    } else {
      console.log("Here are your channels: ", channels);
    }
  });
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Got it. This helps me. Can you give me the docs link to explore more about the other properties like 'list' ?.

Comment: Sure, check out: https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/reference/twilio-node/3.15.0/Twilio.Chat.V1.ServiceContext.ChannelList.html#list